# Reading / Writing to memory in MASM assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Ive been trying to teach myself some very basic assembly (output to console, Arithmetic). I would like to know how i could store somthing (say a byte) in memory and how to read it from memory.

Ideally a answer without using HLA would be be appreciated (if this is possible)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MOV` instruction is what you are looking for!

This is how you load data from memory

```
MOV AL,moffs8* Move byte at (seg:offset) to AL
MOV AX,moffs16* Move word at (seg:offset) to AX
MOV EAX,moffs32* Move doubleword at (seg:offset) to EAX
```

`seg` indicates the [segment registers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#Segment_Registers) (CS, DS, ES, FS, GS, SS-Code Segment, Data Segment, Extra Segment etc)

This is how you move data into the memory

```
MOV moffs8*,AL Move AL to (seg:offset)
MOV moffs16*,AX Move AX to (seg:offset)
MOV moffs32*,EAX Move EAX to (seg:offset)
```

Read about the complete intel x86 instruction set here
http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf